# Julia: create a new folder and file in location relative to script location

Tags: path, julia

Would you happen to know how to get the path of a julia script, in a julia script?

In essence, I built a julia script named `someCode.jl` and it is located in a folder named `repository`.

When I run `someCode.jl`, I would like to create an output folder named `output` in the folder `repository` and put a file `a.txt` in folder `output`.

With an absolute path it works fine, but I want it to be runnable for people who put it in a different path, but I have not been able to find the right syntax yet.

## Attempts

The `pwd()` command returns the directory in which julia is installed, which in this case is: `"E:\\Users\\a\\AppData\\Local\\Julia-1.1.0"` Hence I should either make sure the current path gets updated to the folder in which the script is located when I run it, or get the location of the script itself, in the script code. Neither approaches have yet been successful in julia REPL.

### MWE:

This is the example file `someCode.jl`, I run it by opening the Julia REPL and entering: `include("E:/someCode.jl")`

```
open("c:/repository/output/a.txt", "w") do f
    n1 = "Content of  first line"
    write(f, "$n1")
end
```

If the repository or output folder do not exist yet, it throws error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: SystemError: opening file "c:/repository/output/a.txt": No such file or directory
Stacktrace:
 [1] #systemerror#43(::Nothing, ::Function, ::String, ::Bool) at .\error.jl:134
 [2] systemerror at .\error.jl:134 [inlined]
 [3] #open#309(::Nothing, ::Nothing, ::Nothing, ::Bool, ::Nothing, ::Function, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:283
 [4] #open at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [5] open(::String, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:339
 [6] #open#310(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::getfield(Main, Symbol("##7#8")), ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at .\iostream.jl:367
 [7] open(::Function, ::String, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:367
 [8] top-level scope at none:0
 [9] include at .\boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [11] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [12] include(::String) at .\client.jl:403
 [13] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at E:\someCode.jl:1
```

So I ensured the folders `c:/repository/output` exist, put a second script in called 'someLocalCode.jl`and ran it with`include("C:/repository/someLocalCode.jl")`:

```
open("c:/repository/output/a.txt", "w") do f
    n1 = "Content of  first line"
    write(f, "$n1")
end

open("output/b.txt", "w") do f
    n1 = "Content of  first line"
    write(f, "$n1")
end

open("/output/b.txt", "w") do f
    n1 = "Content of  first line"
    write(f, "$n1")
end

#include("C:/repository/test.jl")
```

Both `output/b.txt` and `/output/b.txt` yield (in essence) the same essence when tested individually:

```
ERROR: LoadError: SystemError: opening file "/output/b.txt": No such file or directory
Stacktrace:
 [1] #systemerror#43(::Nothing, ::Function, ::String, ::Bool) at .\error.jl:134
 [2] systemerror at .\error.jl:134 [inlined]
 [3] #open#309(::Nothing, ::Nothing, ::Nothing, ::Bool, ::Nothing, ::Function, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:283
 [4] #open at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [5] open(::String, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:339
 [6] #open#310(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::getfield(Main, Symbol("##15#16")), ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at .\iostream.jl:367
 [7] open(::Function, ::String, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:367
 [8] top-level scope at none:0
 [9] include at .\boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [11] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [12] include(::String) at .\client.jl:403
 [13] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at C:\repository\someLocalCode.jl:6
```

Whereas the absolute path does function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the options:

- `@__DIR__` macro expanding to a string with the absolute path to the directory of the file containing the macrocall
- `@__FILE__` macro expanding to a string with the path to the file containing the macrocall
- `PROGRAM_FILE` constant containing the script name passed to Julia from the command line

Comment: Is there a possibility to delay FILE expasnsion, eg define a macro in one module and call it in another script and obtain the script name? Similar to \_\_source\_\_.line, but for file? Source's own .file attribute is empty.

Comment: Probably should make it a separate question

Comment: I am not fully clear what you would want to achieve (i.e. what is the problem you want to solve). Why can't you call `@__FILE__` macro in this other other script file? You can delay evaluation of anything by passing it as an expression and then evaluating in a target environment.

Comment: My goal is to separate macro definition and macro execution, the idea on making an expression might work for me. Without it, Iam getting the file name of a definition file, not a file that has a call to a macro. Thanks for the tip, will tr implementing.

Comment: Here is more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486075/get-path-of-the-executed-file-through-external-function-or-macro-in-julia

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much @Bogumil, implemented in the sample script the answer given can become:

```
# Run this script with the following command:
#include("C:/repository/someCode.jl")

# Print output file to absolute location:
open("c:/repository/output/a.txt", "w") do f
    n1 = "Content of  first line"
    write(f, "$n1")
end

# See what the commands do:
println(@__DIR__)
println(@__FILE__)
println("PROGRAM_FILE=", PROGRAM_FILE)

# Concatenate/merge the local directory with the relative output file location
directoryPath = string(@__DIR__, "/output/b.txt")
println("directoryPath concatenation=", directoryPath)

# Write the output file to a relative file location
open(directoryPath, "w") do f
    n1 = "Content of  first line"
    write(f, "$n1")
end
```

Comment: actually to create `directoryPath` it would be safer to use `joinpath` function as this should be more robust, e.g. if your code is to work under Windows and Linux. You could also `cd` to `@__DIR__` and then work on relative paths.