# get path of the executed file through external function or macro in Julia

Tags: path, julia, metaprogramming

I'm trying write a helper function or macro with no arguments that can record the filename and line of where it is called.

The helper is located in a different module and imported to a script, so `@__FILE__` and `@__LINE__` would not point to the right place.

Here is my helper module at `trace.jl`:

```
module Trace
export @trace, Location

struct Location
    file:: String
    line:: Integer
end

macro trace()
    return Location(abspath(PROGRAM_FILE), __source__.line)
end    

end
```

Here is a script `caller.jl`

```
include("trace.jl")
using .Trace

# putting two statements in one line so that line number is the same
println("I want: ", Location(@__FILE__, @__LINE__)); println(" I get: ", @trace)
```

The output of running `julia caller.jl` is below:

```
D:\github\Handout.jl\src>julia caller.jl
I want: Location("D:\\github\\Handout.jl\\src\\caller.jl", 5)
 I get: Location("D:\\github\\Handout.jl\\src\\caller.jl", 5)
```

I'm not sure if PROGRAM_FILE provides me `caller.jl` by accident or there can be more guarantee?

I would have been happier to extract path from `__source__.file` because `__source__.line` points me to the exact line in exact file, but `__source__.file` is `nothing` when I tried.

Here are two pieces in the documentation. The [first one](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Macro-invocation-1):

> In addition to the given argument list, every macro is passed extra arguments named `__source__` and `__module__`.
>
> The argument `__source__` provides information (in the form of a `LineNumberNode` object) about the parser location of the `@ sign` from the macro invocation.

The [second one](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/ast/#Line-numbers-1):

> Source location information is represented as `(line line_num file_name)` where the third component is optional (and omitted when the current line number, but not file name, changes).
>
> These expressions are represented as `LineNumberNode`s in Julia.

Is there possibly a way to climb up `LineNumberNode` chain to get a filename and not `nothing`?

Also maybe there is a way to delay computation of `%__FILE__` until runtime, so that I can use that construct in `trace`?

Similar discussion:
[Julia: create a new folder and file in location relative to script location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223089/julia-create-a-new-folder-and-file-in-location-relative-to-script-location/55225378)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting `__source__` is what is recommended in the Julia manual. Here is an example

#### File `f1.jl`

```
module Trace

export @trace

macro trace()
    return QuoteNode(__source__)
end

end # module
```

#### File `f2.jl`

```
include("f1.jl")

using .Trace

println("I want: ", (@__FILE__, @__LINE__)); println("I get: ", @trace)

x = @trace
dump(x)

println("This is not what you want: ", PROGRAM_FILE)
```

#### File `f3.jl`

```
include("f2.jl")
```

#### Running the above

Now have a look at the output:

```
$ julia f3.jl
I want: ("D:\\f2.jl", 5)
I get: #= D:\f2.jl:5 =#
LineNumberNode
  line: Int64 7
  file: Symbol D:\f2.jl
This is not what you want: f3.jl
```

In particular:

- `@trace` returns you `LineNumberNode` object that has two fields (but I understand this is what you want)
- you can see that `PROGRAM_FILE` gives you a different information: it is a name of the file passed to Julia from the command line (so it is `f3.jl` in our case, although it was called in `f2.jl` file which was `include`d by `f3.jl`).

Is this clearer now?

Comment: Such a clean exposition, thank you! One remaining question: should I attempt to convert filepath from Symbol to String? For example if I want to read the source of f2.jl and will need a path for it.

Comment: Yes, you can convert `Symbol` to `String` and then use this value to e.g. read that file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I derived based on @Bogumił Kamiński answer and [answer on type conversion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-convert-source-file-to-string/27533/3):

```
struct Location
    file:: String
    line:: Integer
end

macro trace()
    return Location(String(__source__.file), __source__.line)
end
```

I was under an impression from the documentation that `QuoteNode` is needed to access `__source__` contents, in fact you just have to convert `Symbol` `__source__.file` to `String`.

Still not clear, why `__source__.file` has to be `Symbol` firsthand, there must be reasons for this.